# The fastest algorithm for returning max length of consecutive same value fields of matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Here is the given example:
[image: given matrix example]

We have the function which takes one matrix and it's number of columns and it's number of rows and returns int (this is gonna be length). For example:

```
     int function (int** matrix, int n, int m)
```

The question is what's the fastest algorithm for implementing this function so it returns the maximum length of consecutive fields with the same value (doesn't matter if those same values are in one column or in one row, in this example on picture it's the 5 fields of one column with value 8)?
Values can be from 0-255 (grayscale for example).
So in the given example function should return 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a bottleneck and the matrix is large, the first optimization to try is to make one pass over the matrix in sequential memory order (row-by-row in C or C++) rather than two.  This is because it's very expensive to traverse a 2d array in the other direction.  Cache and paging behavior are the worst possible.

For this you will need a row-sized array to track the number of consecutive values in the current run within each column.

```
int function (int a[][], int m, int n) {
  if (n <= 0 || m <= 0) return 0;

  int longest_run_len = 1; // Accumulator for the return value.
  int current_col_run_len[n]; // Accumulators for each column
  int current_row_run_len = 1; // Accumulator for the current row.

  // Initialize the column accumulators and check the first row.
  current_col_run_len[0] = 1;
  for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
    current_col_run_len[j] = 1;
    if (a[0][j] ==  a[0][j-1]) {
      if (++current_row_run_len > longest_run_len)
        longest_run_len = current_row_run_len;
    } else current_row_run_len = 1;
  }

  // Now the rest of the rows...
  for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {

    // First column:
    if (a[i][0] == a[i-1][0]) {
      if (++current_col_run_len[0] > longest_run_len)
        longest_run_len = current_col_run_len[0];
    } else current_col_run_len[0] = 1;

    // Other columns.
    current_row_run_len = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[i][j] == a[i][j-1]) {
        if (++current_row_run_len > longest_run_len)
          longest_run_len = current_row_run_len;
      } else current_row_run_len = 1;
      if (a[i][j] == a[i-1][j]) {
        if (++current_col_run_len[j] > longest_run_len)
          longest_run_len = current_col_run_len[j];
      } else current_col_run_len[j] = 1;
    }
  }
  return longest_run_len;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass over each entry of the matrix at least once, so you can't possible do better than O(m*n).

The most straightforward way is to pass over each row and each column once. This will be two passes over the matrix, but the algorithm is still O(m*n).

Any attempt to do it in one pass will probably be a lot more complex.

```
int function (int** matrix, int n, int m) {        
    int best=1;
    for (int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
        int k=1;
        int last=-1;
        for (int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == last) {
                 k++;
                 if (k > best) {
                     best=k;
                 }
            } 
            else {                     
                 k=1;
            }
            last = matrix[i][j];
        }
     }
     for (int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        int k=1;
        int last=-1;
        for (int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == last) {
                 k++;
                 if (k > best) {
                     best=k;
                 }
            } 
            else {                     
                 k=1;
            }
            last = matrix[i][j];
        }
     }
     return best;
}
```